# Mongoose refs not populating json

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to learn MongoDB with a simple Express API. The API works well for fetching individual collections, but when I try to combine multiple collections into one schema using mongoose `ref`, I get a json response containing only the `_id` field.

Here are two Schemas in Mongoose:

```
var LinkSchema = require('./link.js');

var MyInfoSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    title: String,
    links: [ LinkSchema ]
});

var AboutSchema = new Schema({
    img: String,
    description: String
});
```

These work fine in endpoints calling them separately.

I want to have an endpoint that combines these two collections into a single json response. So, I made this model using `ref`

```
var MyInfoSchema = require('./myinfo.js');
var AboutSchema = require('./about.js');

var AllDataSchema = new Schema({
    myinfo: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'MyInfoSchema'
    },
    about: { 
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'AboutSchema'
    }
});
```

My Express API route looks like this

```
var router = express.Router();

router.route('/')
    .get(function(request, response){
        var data = new AllData();

        // add myinfo
        MyInfo.findOne(function(error, info){
            data.myinfo = info;
            console.log(data); // this gives an id
        });

        // add about
        About.findOne(function(error, about){
            data.about = about;
        });

        console.log(data); // this prints nothing
        response.json(data);
    });
```

However, the json response I get is only an `_id`

> ```
> {
>     "_id": "59bfed783f0ba490a34c9ce9"
> }
> ```

Why is the response not populated?

I tried logging to the console. When I put the log inside the `findOne()`, I get an object like this

```
{ _id: 59bfed783f0ba490a34c9ce9,
  myinfo: 59b1ad02d551330000000002 }
```

When I place the log statement outside the find function and before `response.json()`, I get nothing. Why is that? `data` should still be in scope, no?

**Edit:**

As suggested by @Mikey in the answers, I've refactored to use Promises. This is getting closer, but there are 2 problems. 1. The keys for each collection are missing, and 2. It's returning an array for the root structure instead of an object.

Here is the update

```
.get(function(request, response){
    var data = new AllData();

    var p1 = MyInfo.findOne().exec(),
        p2 = Navigation.findOne().exec(),
        p3 = About.findOne().exec(),
        p4 = Contact.findOne().exec();

    Promise.all([p1, p2, p3, p4]).then(function(data) {
        data.myinfo = data[0];
        data.navigation = data[1];
        data.about = data[2];
        data.contact = data[3];
        response.json(data);
    });
});
```

and this is the response

```
[
    {
        "_id": "59b1ad02d551330000000002",
        "title": "Television Tester",
        "name": "Walter P. K.",
        "__v": 0,
        "links": [
            {
                "name": "...",
                "url": "...",
                "_id": "59b1ad02d551330000000004"
            },
            {
                "name": "more...",
                "url": "more...",
                "_id": "59b1ad02d551330000000003"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "59b2e606103ace0000000003",
        "__v": 1,
        "links": [
            {
                "name": "About",
                "url": "#",
                "_id": "59b2e62d103ace0000000009"
            },
            {
                "name": "Stuff",
                "url": "#",
                "_id": "59b2e62d103ace0000000008"
            },
            {
                "name": "Contact",
                "url": "#",
                "_id": "59b2e62d103ace0000000007"
            }
        ]
    }
    ...
]
```

It should be something like this

```
{
  myinfo: {}.
  navigation: {},
  about: {},
  contact: {}
}
```

Comment: you did not save any data, and why are you doing this data.myinfo = info;

Comment: **findOne** is async so your console log runs before the **findOne** callbacks.

Comment: @ArunKillu I am trying to create a JS object structure to return in the response.

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose operations are asynchronous. You need to wait for all the operations to be done before sending a response.

You can either nest your operations

```
router.route('/').get(function(request, response){
    var data = new AllData();

    MyInfo.findOne(function(err, info) {
        data.myinfo = info;
        About.findOne(function (err, about){
            data.about = about;
            response.json(data);
        });
    });
});
```

or use promises (I think it's like this)

```
router.route('/').get(function(request, response){
    var data = new AllData();

    var p1 = MyInfo.findOne().exec(),
        p2 = About.findOne().exec();

    Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(function(data) {
        data.myinfo = data[0];
        data.about = data[1];
        response.json(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: This is helpful. I'm not too experienced with Promises - (looking it up more now), but there are still some problems. See the update to OP.  If `data` is the object created by `AllData()` what is `data[0]` etc. referencing?

Answer (score 1):

**findOne** is async so your console log runs before the **findOne** callbacks.

You might be looking for something more like this, which will query your 'AllData' collection and replace the stored id with the referenced documents for 'myinfo' and 'about':

```
AllData.find()
  .populate('myinfo about')
  .exec(function(error, docs) {
    console.log(docs)
    response.json(docs)
  });
```

Comment: `AllData` is not a document stored in the database, rather it is a data structure composed of multiple smaller collections that I want to return from the API.

Comment: @mhatch If `AllData` is not a document that is stored in the database, then why do you have a schema for it?

Comment: @Mikey That was, indeed, part of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem with the helpful suggestions of the other answerers. Thank you for pointing out the async nature of `find()` and promises. What I needed to make it work was to use a plain JS object for the response structure (instead of a Mongoose Schema), and some variable name cleanup. In the answer by Mikey, and my edit to the question, the response and console.log array being returned was actually the promises array (i.e. the values from p1, p2, p3, etc), not the data structure I wanted to return.

Here is the working code:

```
router.route('/')
    .get(function(request, response){

        var p1 = MyInfo.findOne().exec(),
            p2 = Navigation.findOne().exec(),
            p3 = About.findOne().exec(),
            p4 = Contact.findOne().exec();

        Promise.all([p1, p2, p3, p4]).then(function(docs) {
            var data = {};
            console.log(docs);
            data.myinfo = docs[0];
            data.navigation = docs[1];
            data.about = docs[2];
            data.contact = docs[3];
            response.json(data);
        });
    });
```